# Ensuring no files were deleted from directory at a certain time

Tags: linux, rm, stat, deleted-files

I accidentally started an `rm -rf` on a large directory that I was working in. The directory contains, among other things, a `data` directory containing a number of subdirectories that each contain thousands of text files. Essentially it looks like this

```bsh
$ tree data
data
├── collection0
│   ├── input
│   │   ├── file0.txt
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── file9999.txt
│   └── output
│       ├── file0.txt
│       ├── file1.txt
│       ├── ...
│       └── file9999.txt
├── ...
└── collection99
    ├── input
    │   ├── file0.txt
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── file9999.txt
    └── output
        ├── file0.txt
        ├── file1.txt
        ├── ...
        └── file9999.txt
```

I was able to interrupt the `rm -rf` process pretty quickly, but of course in the half-second or so of execution time a number of files in other subdirectories were deleted.

My question is, is there a way to ascertain with 100% certainty whether a given subdirectory lost any files during this time? It seems as though the `Modify` time on directories that lost files got updated to when the files were deleted, and using this method I *think* no files in the data subdirectories was deleted (assume 2021-09-08 is the date of the `rm -rf` event):

```bsh
$ find data -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec stat {} -c '%n %y' \;
data/collection0/input 2021-08-28 05:45:49.624228368 -0400
data/collection0/output 2021-08-28 05:45:49.624228368 -0400
...
data/collection99/input 2021-08-29 04:55:38.772912003 -0400
data/collection99/output 2021-08-29 04:55:38.772912003 -0400
$ find data -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec stat {} -c '%n %y' \; | grep 2021-09-08
$
```

Is this a reliable method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux man page for `stat(2)` says that:

> The  field  `st_mtime` is changed by file modifications, for example, by `mknod(2)`, `truncate(2)`, `utime(2)`, and `write(2)` (of more than zero bytes).  **Moreover, `st_mtime` of a directory is changed
> by the creation or deletion of files in that directory.**  The `st_mtime` field is not changed for changes in owner, group, hard link count, or mode.
>
> The field `st_ctime` is changed by writing or by setting inode information (i.e., owner, group, link count, mode, etc.).

So, yes, should be able to rely on the modification time being updated if the `rm` touched each directory. Provided of course that it wasn't manually reset afterwards, but in that case, the *change* timestamp (ctime) should be updated. Well, if I understand the man page text correctly, the ctime also updates any time mtime does, so it should be enough to look at just that one.

Also, you can only use mtime to prove the negative. If the timestamp is updated, there's no way to know if it happened due to a file being removed, or another being created, or the timestamp being manually modified.

Comment: Thanks. All I needed in this case was to prove was the negative, as there were no other modifications done.

Does it seem to you like there probably isn't a way to prove the positive ex post facto?

Comment: @AngusL'Herrou, in practice you could probably assume that if the timestamp changed at the same time as `rm` was running, then it's probably due to it. Especially if you know there aren't any other users or programs touching those files. But in principle it might have been something else and the system doesn't really keep logs of what happened. (except for the internals of some log-based or copy-on-write filesystems might, but it's harder to get to those)